# Логический оператор для String

Tags: java, строки, логические-выражения, оператор-присваивания

Есть код:

```
String a = "Hello", b = "Hello";
System.out.println("a==b: " + a==b);
System.out.println("a!=b: " + a!=b);
```

Который выводит следующее значение:

```
false
true
```

Я знаю, что операторы `==` и `!=` сравнивают ссылки, отсюда и результат вывода (false,true),
но куда из строки подевались стринговые значения `"a==b: "` и `"a!=b: "` не понимаю.
Думаю тут что-то связанное с приведением типов, но до конца понять не могу. Может кто-нибудь пояснить конкретнее?

Comment: _отсюда и результат вывода (false,true)_  - Нет. Выведи просто a==b и a !=b и результат будет ``true`` и ``false``, а не false и true.

Comment: Кстати в первой версии вопроса были строки `Hello` и `One`, а не две одинаковые строки, поэтому свой ответ я писал под этот случай. А так Эникейщик правильно заметил, что сравнение `Hello` и `Hello` должно дать `true` даже по `==`. Ладно, поправлю ответ тогда.

Comment: Да, все верно,  в первой версии вопроса были строки Hello и One, а не две одинаковые строки. 
Byb, благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У оператора сложения `+` приоритет выше, чем у оператора сравнения `==`. Поэтому выражение

```
System.out.println("a==b: " + a==b);
```

расценивается как

```
System.out.println(("a==b: " + a)==b);
```

То есть, мы складываем две строки и результат сравниваем с `b`, получая в ответе просто `false`.

Аналогично для того случая, где мы используем оператор `!=`: его приоритет также ниже, чем у оператора `+`.

Для того, чтобы на экран было выведено то, что вы хотите, результат сравнения строк нужно брать в скобки:

```
System.out.println("a==b: " + (a==b));
```

Тогда мы получим:

```
a==b: true
```

Для случая с `!=`, соответственно, аналогично.

Это потому, что такая запись уже будет расценена как сложение двух строк. Первая строка - `a==b`, вторая - булево выражение `false`/`true`, приводимое по ходу дела к строке.

---

Если бы мы ушли от такого сочетания операторов `+`, `==` и `!=`, то для ожидаемого вывода нем не понадобилось бы расставлять скобки. Например, если мы сравним строки посредством метода `equals()`

```
System.out.println("a==b: " + a.equals(b));
```

то в результате получим

```
a==b: true
```

Очевидно, в этом случае содержимое `println()` уже легко и однозначно распознаётся как сложение двух строк.

---

Как правильно заметил @Эникейщик, для идентичных строк `Hello` и `Hello` результаты, выдаваемые операторами `==` и `!=`, будут соответственно `true` и `false`. У вас получилось наоборот по тем причинам, которые я описал выше, а не из-за "сравнения ссылок".

А почему для одинаковых строк оператор `==` в данном случае выдаст `true` - можно прочитать в соседнем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Да, приоритеты операций тут и определили результат выражения. Но я хочу дополнить.

Вообще-то, в Java есть такая штука, как пул стрингов. Для строк, значение которых известно до запуска программы, все переменные String с одинаковыми значениями получают ссылку на один и тот же объект с этим значением.
У вас как раз при компиляции уже известно, что и a, и b, будут равны "Hello".
Поэтому и сравнение методом equals(), и сравнение через ==, оба должны давать true.

```
a.equals(b)  //true  
a == b       //true  
a != b       //false
```